# Speeding up TF/Keras LSTM text generation on GPU?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras

The tensorflow official example for text generation (https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/text/text_generation.ipynb) runs in a loop as defined below. The text generation feels slow, and according to NVTOP only uses a fraction of the available GPU resources (15-20%).

[image]

Any suggestions on how to speed up text generation? A quick look at cprofiler shows that 90% of the time is spent on the single line `predictions = model(input_eval)`, so I don't think there are a lot of gains to be had elsewhere.

Also, the Tensorflow/Keras documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict recommends calling the function just as is done below...

> this method is designed for performance in large scale inputs. For
>   small amount of inputs that fit in one batch, directly using **call**
>   is recommended for faster execution, e.g., model(x), or model(x,
>   training=False)

Any suggestions on how to speed up text generation? Would it be possible to better use the GPU by generating multiple lines at the same time?

```
def generate_text(model, start_string):
  # Evaluation step (generating text using the learned model)

  # Number of characters to generate
  num_generate = 1000

  # Converting our start string to numbers (vectorizing)
  input_eval = [char2idx[s] for s in start_string]
  input_eval = tf.expand_dims(input_eval, 0)

  # Empty string to store our results
  text_generated = []

  # Low temperatures results in more predictable text.
  # Higher temperatures results in more surprising text.
  # Experiment to find the best setting.
  temperature = 1.0

  # Here batch size == 1
  model.reset_states()
  for i in range(num_generate):
      predictions = model(input_eval)
      # remove the batch dimension
      predictions = tf.squeeze(predictions, 0)

      # using a categorical distribution to predict the character returned by the model
      predictions = predictions / temperature
      predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()

      # We pass the predicted character as the next input to the model
      # along with the previous hidden state
      input_eval = tf.expand_dims([predicted_id], 0)

      text_generated.append(idx2char[predicted_id])

  return (start_string + ''.join(text_generated))
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `@tf.function` to this `generate_text` function? There are some things you'll need to fix to get that to work, but that will get you out of eager execution to graph execution where things are better compiled.

Answer (score 2):

To speed up the processing, I have two suggestions,

1. As you have GPU support, you may want to set `unroll=True` of the `GRU` layer. As per the Keras `GRU` [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/gru/), setting `unroll=True` reduces some computation by using some extra memory. As your GPU consumption is quite less, you may want to use `unroll=True`. Using this setting, you may notice up to `2x` speed boost (depending on the circumstances). However, you should avoid using unroll if the input sequence is too long.
2. I noticed that the text-generation architecture you [linked](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/text/text_generation.ipynb) uses `GRU` layer before a `Dense` layer. The `GRU` is given a parameter `return_sequences=True`. This causes the `GRU` layer to pass unnecessary output values to the following `Dense` layers and requires more computation. Generally, `return_sequences=True` should be only set if the following layer of the model is also an RNN layer. Therefore, try setting the parameter `return_sequences=False`. This may also improve performance.

Finally, the `model(x, training=False)` really works. I believe by maintaining these three issues, you may notice a significant performance improvement.

Comment: If you set `unroll=True`, then the CUDNN implementation of GRU will not be used. The CUDNN implementation is much faster (about 10x) than the alternative GPU implementation.

Comment: Yes you are right. In most cases CUDNN outperforms general implementation. But, I have noticed that in some (I believe in most) cases using 'unroll' improves the performance (I don't know why, but I have experienced it). That is why I already added a phrase "(depending on the circumstances)".

Comment: Also, I remember answering this to a previous question. I experienced performance boost up also did the person who questioned. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673685/tensorflow-model-prediction-is-slow

Comment: actually, using the unroll=True gave about a 50% speed up in my case. I'm running a conv net followed by a single fc lstm layer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can speed generation. You are doing `num_generate` forward calls on your model for an input with batch size of 1. While during training, you can operate on the whole sequence and compute a loss over it, during predicting each new character depends on the previously generated ones and the generation function doesn't run in parallel.

If you want to see higher GPU utilization, you could call predict on a batch of inputs seeded with different starting characters - this relates to your question about 'generating multiple lines at the same time'.

You could also try using the same starting character and tinker with the hidden state to input into the model, e.g. seeing what a randomly sampled state for the batch produces or extracting hidden state vectors for that starting character from training examples and populating the batched hidden state with those so your models goes in different directions from this initial character.

Answer (score 0):

Better performance could be also achieved by using a different toolkit for the inference e.g. [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). It optimizes your model by converting to Intermediate Representation (IR), performing graph pruning and fusing some operations into others while preserving accuracy. Then it uses vectorization in runtime.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets are below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Save your model as SavedModel**

OpenVINO is not able to convert the HDF5 model, so you have to save it as SavedModel first.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from custom_layer import CustomLayer
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device, e.g., CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what the best choice for you is, use AUTO. You care about latency, so I suggest adding a performance hint (as shown below) to use the device that fulfills your requirement.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="AUTO", config={"PERFORMANCE_HINT":"LATENCY"})

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO. OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware.