# Tensorflow model prediction is slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a `TensorFlow` model with a single `Dense` layer:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)])
model.build(input_shape=(None, None, 25))
```

I construct a single input vector in `float32`:

```py
np_vec = np.array(np.random.randn(1, 1, 25), dtype=np.float32)
vec = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(np_vec), dtype=tf.float32)
```

I want to feed that to my model for prediction, but it is very slow.
If I call `predict` or `__call__` it takes a really long time, compared to doing the same operation in NumPy.

1. Call `%timeit model.predict(vec)`:

   > 10 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ms per loop
2. Call the model as is `%timeit model(vec, training=False)`:

   > 1000 loops, best of 3: 806 µs per loop
3. Perform the multiplication operation myself

   ```py
   weights = np.array(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0])   
   %timeit np_vec @ weights
   ```

   > 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 µs per loop
4. Perform the multiplication myself using torch

   > 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.57 µs per loop

Google Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RCnTM24RUI4VkykVtdRtRdUVEkAHdu4A?usp=sharing

**How can I make my TensorFlow model faster in inference time?**
Especially because I don't only have a `Dense` layer, but I also use an `LSTM` and I don't want to reimplement that in NumPy.

Comment: you could try using batch training, instead of optimizing your model for every sample.

Comment: This is not training time, this is inference time. I need to make my model as fast as possible for a single sample at a time

Comment: Your conclusions are completely incorrect, the first case you converted the input to a symbolic tensor, while predict takes numpy arrays, so a conversion is happening that makes it slow. The second case is only doing a symbolic computation which is not really what you want. I do not see a problem here.

Comment: Dear @Dr.Snoopy, all of the `results` from every operation are the exact same. I added that to the colab now.

Comment: We do not look at colab, all code/results have to be in your question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy All of the operations return the same results. To prove that **to you** I added that in the colab. This is trivial for the issue because indeed all of my code is equivalent

Comment: No, they are not doing the same computation, as I said, predict takes numpy arrays, and you are not passing np_vec to predict. Also you are not considering that tensorflow does have some overhead that is independent of the input size. These computations are too small to say anything.

Comment: I my experience model(input) and computing it with weights of layers with numpy is roughly the same, when the model gets bigger. Only model.predict(input) does take approx. 100 times longer. 

For me, if I want single inferences, model(input) is sufficiently better than predict, and easier to use than numpy computation.

Still left to to is a comparison to pytorch with bigger models.

Answer (score 3):

The whole story lies behind the implementation of the LSTM layer in Keras. The Keras LSTM layer has a default argument `unroll=False`. This causes the LSTM to run a symbolic loop (loop causes more time). Try adding an extra argument to the LSTM as `unroll=True`.

```
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, unroll=True)
```

This may result in up to a 2x speed boost up (tested on my machine, using `%timeit model(vec, training=False)`). However, using `unroll=True` may cause taking more ram for larger sequences. For more inquiry, please have a look at the Keras LSTM [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/).

Comment: Thank you, this indeed is correct. Adding `unroll=True` speeds up from 3.4ms to 2.3ms, however, my sequences are very very long (10000-50000) so its not suitable. One thing I did notice from this though is changing `return_sequences` to `False` actually changes the time to 1.84ms, which is something I can use

Comment: sorry I did not notice it. Yes, indeed it will work. But, I would like to inform you that you should only use `return_sequences=False`, only on the last LSTM layer (before the dense layer). Otherwise, you may gain a performance boost, but you would lose some important features. Hope it helps.